# Flow of a complex vector field?

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds

Suppose I have a vector field X over a m-dimensional analytical manifold $M\subset \mathbb{C}^n$; how can I define the flow of $X$? Is it done in the same way as for the real case, but instead of taking intervals on the real line I take open sets of the complex plane?

Thanks.

Comment: I think usually the word "flow" means that the time coordinate is real.  So if you have a vector field on a complex manifold, its "flow" would still be defined for real values of $t$.  However, I don't see any obstacle to defining a flow-like map with complex time values as you have suggested.

Comment: Well now, I have found a book in this website: http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~yakov/ that seems to shed some light on the subject.

Comment: @Marra Can you please say which book is it exactly?

Comment: For other people looking for the source, @Marra probably meant https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~yakov/thebook1.pdf

Comment: In case the PDF gets ever removed: the book is "Lectures on Analytic Differential Equations" by Yulij Ilyashenko and Sergei Yakovenko.